# Unwanted redirect in Chrome when appending "@anydomain.com"

Tags: apache, google-chrome, redirect

I just notice if we append "@anydomain.com" to any URL Chrome (and also FF) redirects user to the domains appended.

For example:

http://www.google.com@facebook.com/ - Will redirect to facebook.com
http://www.facebook.com@google.com/ - Will redirect to google.com

I would like to prevent it from my website, does anyone know anything about it?

Thanks in advance!

-B.J.

---

Adding more info:
If I try to add a '/' before the '@', like this:

http://www.google.com/@facebook.com/

Then Google gives me 404 page not found... But my website still redirects with the '/'

Comment: If you mean that you want to prevent, for example, redirection like `http://www.mydomain.com@evildomain.com/`, you can't -- the redirection occurs without ever touching your server.

Comment: I see @EdCottrell ... What about if I have the URL like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/@evildomain.com/ Note I added '/' right before the '@'.. Then it hits my server right?
Because I see facebook and google give me a 404 page not found
But my sever still redirects... Any hint how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't redirect in that scenario. You have a rule in .htaccess or something in a framework that is doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it.
The issue was in the Apache configuration, the permanent redirect I have to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS had the wrong template, it was missing a final slash '/'.

So when accessing:
http://mydomain.com/@anotherdomain.com
it was redirecting to https://mydomain.com@anotherdomain.com without the final slash, and the browser default behaviour was to redirect to anotherdomain.com without even hitting my server.

It was only about adding the slash on the redirect clause I have.
Redirect permanent https://mydomain.com/

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol is used as part of the URI scheme to login users to a site.
If you notice, as soon as you click it says "You are about to log in Facebook.com with the username..."
Its part of the HTTP protocol. You can't really do anything about it.

Read : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: I don't think so.. I didn't get when you say "You are about to log in Facebook.com __with the username__" What username? I didn't see anything like that...